# Is there a term for "all primitive types" that can be used as an input to a method?

Tags: java

if I want to make a method that does something to any object that is used as input, I can write a method header that looks like this:

```
public static void example(Object o){...}
```

is there a term for "all primitive types" the same way that `Object` contains all non primitive variables?

Comment: In this case, you must have to cast it every time.

Comment: Instead of using primitive type, you can use the Wrapper type.  int: Integer, char: Character, doube: Double, boolean:Boolean.  Then, you can lump them together as object.

Comment: No, there is no common primitive supertype. That would go against the dictionary meaning of primitive: "not developed or derived from anything else".

Comment: `java.lang.Object` already does that, via auto-boxing, but if you want to get numeric or boolean values without too much mucking around you could provide overloads for `Number` and `Boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a type that encompasses only primitive types, but you can use a wrapper type and throw an error if the input given is not of one of those types.

```
public static void example(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof Double)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error Message");
    }
}
```

This code only checks the `Double` wrapper type, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wrapper type for primitives.  Then, they become objects and you can use them wherever you can use Object.

```
public class Main{
   
   static void print(Object o){
      System.out.println(o);
   }
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer i = 5;
        Double d = 5.5;
        Boolean b = true;
        
        print(i);
        print(d);
        print(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: They become objects even if you don't use the wrapper types yourself, via auto-boxing.

Answer (score 0):

No, but method overloads are usually how that is accomplished.  For example:

```
// Notice this method is private.
private static void exampleImpl(Object obj) { /* ... */ }

// And these are public, so it is only possible for an outside caller
// to pass (wrapped) primitives to the above method.
public static void example(boolean value) {
    exampleImpl(value);
}
public static void example(byte value) {
    exampleImpl(value);
}
public static void example(char value) {
    exampleImpl(value);
}
public static void example(short value) {
    exampleImpl(value);
}
public static void example(int value) {
    exampleImpl(value);
}
public static void example(long value) {
    exampleImpl(value);
}
public static void example(float value) {
    exampleImpl(value);
}
public static void example(double value) {
    exampleImpl(value);
}
```

Comment: That’s what I’m currently using. I was hoping there was a way I could just have 2 methods: 1 for objects and 1 for primitives, so I didn’t have to edit 9 methods every time I want to make it do more.

Comment: @AriYeger The Java SE APIs have the same challenge, and so far have addressed it the same way.  However, [the eventual addition of “primitive classes”](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/402) may change that.

Answer (score -1):

There is not such thing, but you can use wrapper types with generics. Here is a simple program to demonstrate this:

```
public class Test{
   
   static <T> void genericMethod(T t){
      System.out.println(t);
   }
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer intNum = 10;
        Double doubleNum = 36.5;
        Boolean aBoolean = true;
        Character character = 'a';
        
        genericMethod(intNum);
        genericMethod(doubleNum);
        genericMethod(aBoolean);
        genericMethod(character);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really accomplish anything beyond the original code.